# read, manipulate and export multiple .dta Files using a for Loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I have multiple time series (each in a seperate file), which I need to adjust seasonally using the season package in R and store the adjusted series each in a seperate file again in a different directory.
The Code works for a single county.

So I tried to use a for Loop but R is unable to use the read.dta with a wildcard.

I'm new to R and using usually Stata so the question is maybe quite stupid and my code quite messy.

Sorry and Thanks in advance

Nathan

```
for(i in 1:402)
{
alo[i] <- read.dta("/Users/nathanrhauke/Desktop/MA_NH/Data/ALO/SEASONAL_ADJUSTMENT/SINGLE_SERIES/County[i]")
alo_ts[i] <-ts(alo[i], freq = 12, start = 2007)
m[i] <- seas(alo_ts[i])

original[i]<-as.data.frame(original(m[i]))
adjusted[i]<-as.data.frame(final(m[i]))
trend[i]<-as.data.frame(trend(m[i]))
irregular[i]<-as.data.frame(irregular(m[i]))

County[i] <- data.frame(cbind(adjusted[i],original[i],trend[i],irregular[i], deparse.level =1))
write.dta(County[i], "/Users/nathanrhauke/Desktop/MA_NH/Data/ALO/SEASONAL_ADJUSTMENT/ADJUSTED_SERIES/County[i].dta")
}
```

Comment: How are your files named? In your example above you read the same STATA file over and over. You need to combine it somehow with `paste` to produce the correct file name. How does your `County` vector look?

Comment: Hey ekstroem, thanks for your help! The `County`  vector is just one column with Employment Data for a German County over time. The name of the STATA files are County1.dta County2.dta etc. The Code provided by Thomas below is taking care of all mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good place to use a function and the `*apply` family. As noted in a comment, your main problem is likely to be that you're using Stata-like character string construction that will not work in R. You need to use `paste` (or `paste0`, as here) rather than just passing the indexing variable directly in the string like in Stata. Here's some code:

```
f <- function(i) {
  d <- read.dta(paste0("/Users/nathanrhauke/Desktop/MA_NH/Data/ALO/SEASONAL_ADJUSTMENT/SINGLE_SERIES/County",i,".dta"))
  alo_ts <- ts(d, freq = 12, start = 2007)
  m <- seas(alo_ts)
  original <- as.data.frame(original(m))
  adjusted <- as.data.frame(final(m))
  trend <- as.data.frame(trend(m))
  irregular <- as.data.frame(irregular(m))
  County <- cbind(adjusted,original,trend,irregular, deparse.level = 1)
  write.dta(County, paste0("/Users/nathanrhauke/Desktop/MA_NH/Data/ALO/SEASONAL_ADJUSTMENT/ADJUSTED_SERIES/County",i,".dta"))
  invisible(County)
}

# return a list of all of the resulting datasets
lapply(1:402, f)
```

It would probably also be a good idea to take advantage of relative directories by first setting your working directory:

```
setwd("/Users/nathanrhauke/Desktop/MA_NH/Data/ALO/SEASONAL_ADJUSTMENT/")
```

Then you can simply the above paths to:

```
d <- read.dta(paste0("./SINGLE_SERIES/County",i,".dta"))
```

and

```
write.dta(County, paste0("./ADJUSTED_SERIES/County",i,".dta"))
```

which will make your code more readable and reproducible should, for example, someone ever run it on another computer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas, for the helpful comments and the Code! It works perfectly!